# unzip .gz file as a directory

Tags: linux

New to Linux

had gzip the folder as abc.gz. now when i try using the gunzip command the file doesn't come as folder, instead the output file has become abc. could someone let me know the command to unzip the abc.gz as a folder.

thanks

Comment: gunzip will unzip the content of a zip file. If the content was a folder then the output will be a folder. If the content was a file then the content of it will be a file.

Comment: Which command did you try? Please mention that properly in the question!

Comment: @shekhar $gunzip abc.gz is the command. but it doesn't came as folder.

Comment: @vahid when you gunzip the file, it doesn't come as a folder which was a folder before zip, it comes as a single file

Comment: @santh: a `.gz` compresses one single file. To compress multiple files, you first create a **tarball**: a file that contains multiple files into a single one. Later in the process, you then compress that `.tar` file resulting in a `.tar.gz`.

Comment: You probably have a `gzip`ped `tar` file. Use the `file` command to figure out what the file is, e.g. `file abc`. If this says `tar archive`, you can use the `tar` command to get your files back, e.g. `tar xvf abc`.

Answer (score 6):

`gzip` compresses **one single file**, and **doesn't store the original filename** (you could for instance compress a network stream you captured once, that didn't had a name) into that file. If you need to compress multiple files, you need to make use of a **tarball** (a collection of files packed into a single file, a tarball stores the name of the files as well).

When you read the manual of `gzip` (`man gzip`), you can see that you simply use

```
gzip -d < "file.gz" > "realfile.dat"
```

to decompress the file stored in "file.gz" and save it as "realfile.dat".

Now if you have compressed **multiple files**, you need to do this using the earlier called **tarball**. Perhaps you dropped the extension. In that case, you can first decompress the `.gz` file and then use `tar` to expand it using:

```
gzip -d < "file.tar.gz" | tar -x
```

Here `tar` reads from `stdin` (data provided by `gzip` and expands it). Since people use `gzip` on `tar` a lot of times, `tar` made it more convenient using:

```
tar -xzf "file.tar.gz"
```

where `z` means you want to run `gzip` on it, and `f` means that you read from a file instead of the `stdin`.

In order to create such archive, you again first need to use tar:

```
tar -c "folder" | gzip -c > "file.tar.gz"
```

Or, `tar` again comes up with a shorter way to do this:

```
tar -czf "file.tar.gz" "folder"
```

Comment: Now i tried your suggestions as below, had created a new folder as test1 and tried zip it using $gzip -rc test1 > test1.gz --> then used the command $gunzip test.gz and then tried your command $gzip -d < "test1.tar.gz" | tar -x - errors -bash: test1.tar.gz: No such file or directory
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors.  Could you please guide me what should i do now

Comment: Well evidently that doesn't work because you named your file `test1.gz`. Do you know how IO-redirection works (the `<` and `>`)?

Comment: You better don't use `gzip -r`, it concatenates files together. You should use `tar -c test1 | gzip -c > "test1.tar.gz"`

Comment: @santh: well if you have read the answer, you would see that this is evident: `gzip` works on **one single** input and output file. You need `tar` to let it work on multiple files. So you need to compress it with `tar -c "folder" | gzip -c > "file.tar.gz"` and unzip it with `gzip -d < "file.tar.gz" | tar -x`...

Comment: @santh: the `-r` flag more or less **concatenates** files together, without making storing the **origin of the data**. In other words: information is lost.

Comment: deleted the base folder now. what i have now is test1.gz, so you want me to use the command $ tar -c "test1.gz" | gzip -c > "test1.tar.gz" and unzip it with $gzip -d < "test1.tar.gz" | tar -x is that correct?

Comment: No! `tar -c "folder" | gzip -c > "test1.tar.gz"`. You need to provide the folder you want to compress, not the tar file... In order to compress it **you need to use `tar` so that the information about the structure of the files is maintained**.

Answer (score 3):

`gunzip` functions as a decompression algorithm only.

so `gunzip` would simply leave with the file decompressed, on which you would then need e.g. to `tar xvf file.tar`.

The `z` option of `tar` is simply a shortcut to do the decompression with `gzip` along with extracting the files.

Comment: can I hear at least what is the reason for downvoting ?